# Error when trying to connect to remote node in Corda OS4.4 [Connection closed due to error on remote side: CREATE_ADDRESS]

Tags: corda

FYI, I am not using docker. Connecting directly to remote by updating the additional-node-infos directory with the remote node's nodeinfo. I am able to connect to the remote node from the local node. However the remote node is giving the following error:

Connection closed due to error on remote side: `AMQ119032: User: SystemUsers/Peer does not have permission='CREATE_ADDRESS' on address p2p.inbound.DLCm69d1XjYRnqA64iizRneXMu8mv5CrnDugTF2rz42U55` {conn=[id: 0x43b26f57, L:/192.168.1.181:52874 - R:/192.168.1.171:10004],

Comment: Additional Info: [nioEventLoopGroup-2-7] engine.ConnectionStateMachine. - Connection closed due to error on remote side: `AMQ119032: User: SystemUsers/Peer does not have permission='CREATE_ADDRESS' on address p2p.inbound.DLFVXm2Btp4bmCrqGNyCcq9uetDusRNppm8TXnfVEGokcq

Comment: Have you made sure they are in the same network? ie. both nodes share the same root CA
Ref: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/messaging.html#security

Comment: That was it. I only copied over the nodeinfo files and the network parameters initially and not the certificates after running the network bootstrapper. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping up the answer:

You have to check the `nodeinfo` files and the network parameters of the nodes to make sure they are in the same network

---

The error message comes from artemis, the embedded message queue broker in Corda.

The artemis picks up the same CA from the node and so the nodes must share the same root CA

ie. The nodes have to be in the same Corda network.

Detail explanation: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/messaging.html#security